# Using % in SQL query

Tags: java, sql

```
SELECT MAX(sm_version) AS version_latest, 
       user_type       AS role_performed 
FROM   usage_database 
WHERE  user_id LIKE ( '"+%eid_upper+"' ) 
        OR user_id LIKE ( '"+eid_lower+"' ) 
GROUP  BY user_type
```

This is my query. I have designed the database in such a way that I have to `%` in the query. If I execute this query on SQL developer, then it works fine. But when I execute this in Java code which I put in JSP file, then it the following error occurs:

> Syntax error on token "%", invalid Expression

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: DON"T USE STRING CONCATENATION TO BUILD QUERIES!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no good with JSP but shouldn't the `%` be part of the query string if you want to use it as an SQL wildcard?, ie

```
WHERE  user_id LIKE ( '%"+eid_upper+"' )
```

*Edit:* Usual comments about SQL injection, yada yada yada

Comment: @user563577 This answer doesn't deserve the "accept". First, Fred was first and secondly, the answer is terrible

Comment: Brown: You could delete it.  Maybe there's even a badge for that (deleting the accepted answer) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE  user_id LIKE ( '%"+eid_upper+"' )
```

Comment: Only the OP can change the accepted answer.  You'll have to wait until he comes back (if he does).

Answer (score 1):

use prepared statements and bind variables!

```
 where user_id like ( '%' || ? )
```

Comment: come to think of it, you also have to escape special matching characters (like % and _ ) in your `eid_upper`